# How to get password from database

Tags: database, ion-auth

I have created user using ion auth library, the password is saved as encoded format like below:
"$2a$07$SeBknntpZror9uyftVopmu61qg0ms8Qv1yV6FG.kQOSM.9QhmTo36" 
How can we get this encoded password to original password back.

Is this possible or We need to create rest page for that user?

Comment: You cannot. It's a one-way encryption

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible, and it is by design. Good applications don't store passwords in such a way that they can be later retrieved. This is good for the users - no rogue sysadmin can take their email and password and try other sites; and for the sysadmins themselves - if the database is hacked/leaked, then the users don't really need to worry about having other accounts broken into (and then suing the sysadmin).

What you see here is called [password hashing](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) (sometimes incorrectly termed *one-way encryption*).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get that password back.
I think you want to get password back for reset password.
If i am right then right approach is to send user reset password link.
And ask him to regenerate password again.